# IIdentity, IPrincipal or IUser: what's the difference?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to implement simple role based authentication + authorization in an MVC5 application, but I'm getting some headache trying to understand all the parts involved in Identity framework

I'm reading several tutorials and guides, but I stil haven't a clear idea.

In particular: which is the difference among `IIdentity`, `IPrincipal` or `IUser` interfaces? Which of them should I implement?

Comment: `IIdentity` against user's prim information, `IPrincipal` against user's role information (RBAC),`IUser` sorry? I have no idea about it

Comment: `IUser` is part of AspNet.Identity. You need it if you expect to work with Identity objects such as the `UserManager` or `SignInManager`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

'IPrincipal' is a [.Net framework's interface](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/principal/iprincipal.cs,22):

```
public interface IPrincipal {
    // Retrieve the identity object
    IIdentity Identity { get; }

    // Perform a check for a specific role
    bool IsInRole (string role);
}
```

This interface defines the basic functionality of logged in user. 
Object implementing this interface represents the security context under which your code is running. You can get different flavors of `IPrincipal` in .Net: `ClaimsPrincipal`, `WindowsPrincipal` and others - all depends on the framework you are using. If you are working with Asp.Net Identity framework, you'll be dealing with `ClaimsPrincipal`. 
Usually you don't need to implement this interface.

`IIdentity` represents user's permissions. For Asp.Net Identity framework you'll be dealing with [ClaimsIdentity](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/claims/ClaimsIdentity.cs,31). 
Again, this is something you don't need to implement.

[Here is more documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftx85f8x(v=vs.110).aspx) about the `IPrincipal` and `IIDentity`.

`IUser` is part of Asp.Net Identity framework. If you are using Entity Framework part of Identity, [you'll be provided with](https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/IdentityUser.cs) `IdentityUser` class that you can inherit and extend. This is a model for you to implement.

Basically `IdentityUser` is a POCO that is preserved into a database. And when user is logged in, information from `IdentityUser` will be transformed into `ClaimsPrincipal` and `ClaimsIdentity` by the framework. And when you access `HttpContext.Current.User` you will be given `ClaimsPrincipal`.

Hope this clears things up for you.